# how to integrate Spring-security-saml into an existing application that uses Spring-security?

Tags: spring-security, saml

We have an existing application that uses Spring security, so we already have a securityContext.xml file that has the a customEntryPoint which extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint. This works perfectly. Now I want to add a Single sign on button that implement the SAML 2 to a customer IDP. How to configure this in the securityContext.xml file. I have downloaded the spring-security-saml sample and run it successfully with SSOCircle as an IDP. But I have been struggling to combine it with the other securityContext.xml. How can I have two entry points  in the same securityContext.xml? Any example is appreciated.